# Save selection at beginning of macro and set it to be the same at the end of macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that selects things in a sheet.

Prior to running the main section of the macro I want to save the active selection, so that I can set the same selection at the end of the macro.

I've tried the solution below, but it doesn't work. I'd appreciate suggestions.

```
Dim rng As Range

'Beginning of macro
rng = Range(ActiveSheet.Selection) 'Object doesn't support this property or method

'Main section

'End of macro
rng.Select
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution offered by `tmoore82` is the best way to go (+1)

For completeness you can also save the `Address` as a string:

```
Dim selectionAddress as String
selectionAddress = Selection.Address 'e.g. A1 is "$A$1"

'Your macro

Range(selectionAddress).Select 'At end of macro select cell A1
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `rng = Range(ActiveSheet.Selection)`, it should be `Set rng = Selection`.